# D3 Sankey node color arrangement

Tags: node.js, d3.js, colors, sankey-diagram

I want to change d3 sankey node color. This is data sample[data-sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5eGk.png) and I tried below coding but it didnt work;

```js
color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(["A","B","C","D","E","F",])
.range(["#FD3E35","#FFA500","#0000FF","#00ff00","#bee0e6","#bec2e6"]);
```

with below code,

```
.style("fill", function (d) {
    return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
  })
```

My first question what is the function of this coding? ***d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")***

Also can i change the color of nodes with my csv document with adding a column "color"?

Answer (score 1):

First off, in your data sample there's no column with the name "name", so d.name is actually `undefined`. I'm going to guess you want to set the color depending on the source (you can change it for target if you want).

To do this, your color function is correct, however your call needs to be changed to use `d.source` instead of `d.name`.

```js
.style("fill", (d) => color(d.source.replace(/ .*/, "")))
```

What `.replace(/ .*/, "")` is doing here, is replacing everything mathced by the regular expression `/ .*/` with an empty string `""`. However, that specific regular expression means that everything after and including the first whitespace `" "` will be removed. So if your string would be `"Hello, World!"`, the string returned by that replace would be `"Hello,"` If this isn't an issue for your data, you could just do:

```js
.style("fill", (d) => color(d.source))
```

Regarding your last question, you can use a column with the color to be used for every link. To do this you need to be careful that the color put is either an [accepted CSS color name](http://csscolornames.com/) or a HEX color code. If this would be the case, your data should have the color in the object passed by d3, so you can use:

```js
.style("fill", (d) => d.color)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. Issue is sold now. I changed last part .style("fill", (d) => color(d.name)) with this, there was no need to add .replace command. Thank you!

Comment: @juniord3 glad I could help! Also, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) this answer by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this however :) .